Authentication flow for a service that uploads to OneDrive via Microsoft Graph API
I am trying to use the Graph API C# client library to upload to a OneDrive folder. This will be for a scheduled service that periodically uploads files to OneDrive. I have been unable to figure out the appropriate authentication flow for this scenario.
I've tried authenticating in a variety of ways, but have been unsuccessful so far. I've registered the application in Entra and created a client secret. IT has told me they prefer not to grant app-only access permissions, so I believe this means I need to use delegated access, correct? They are also reluctant to create new service accounts, but I think in this case I'll need one, won't I?
In the meantime, I am trying to authenticate with my own account. I've tried to use ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default") to get a token and pass it into BaseBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider, but I'm confused about whether this is appropriate for delegated access, and I get errors like "Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token." which I'm unsure how to overcome.
What is the appropriate auth-flow for this scenario? Which library classes should I be looking at?

Update: IT have relented and granted application permissions to one particular Site, which seems reasonable. So I can now use the client credentials flow. Next problem is to figure out why it works with Postman, but not programmatically via MSAL.

Suppose you are using Graph C# SDK v5. Use Azure.Identity NuGet package. Then you can authenticate as a user
string[] scopes = {"Files.ReadWrite.All"};

var interactiveBrowserCredentialOptions = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions() {
                ClientId = clientId
};
var interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(interactiveBrowserCredentialOptions);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveBrowserCredential, scopes);

You should be able to access all OneDrive files where the user has an access. IT can create 'service user account' with disabled MFA.
With application permission Files.ReadWrite.All, the app can access all OneDrives and there isn't a direct way to restrict the app to specific OneDrive.
In case you want to upload files to a specific SharePoint site and it's Document Library, IT can grant application permission Sites.Selected and then restrict access to a specific SharePoint site.

Thanks. What I don't understand is how this is supposed to work with a scheduled service app, where we can't interactively log in via a browser.
